# Текст в TextView не более 2х строк, а если больше, то три точки добавить. Как сделать?

Tags: android, android-textview

Нужно отобразить текст в `TextView`, но не более 2х строк, а если больше, то добавить три точки в конце. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
android:maxLines="2"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="false"
```